# limit number of images on a tinymce editor?

Tags: image, numbers, tinymce, limit, justboil.me

there is some way to limit the number of images in the tinymce textarea to just one image? does this apply to the jbimages plugin too? (jbimages uploads the images with the < img > tag) I need to set a limit to avoid overloads on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the jbimages plugin.
But you could check for `$(editor.getBody()).find('img')` to get the number of images in your editor and remove enough of them so that only one if left.